# Is there any possibility to paste content of clipboard in Home Screen Widget for android 10?

Tags: android, android-widget, home-screen-widget, android-clipboardmanager

I am trying to create a widget which takes an input of serial key from users. 
I also added a paste button for convenience because serial key is 14 digits long. Below code was working fine for devices before android 10

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
String serial = item.getText();
```

Then I compare serial with our serial regex. 
Issue is, Current snippet returns null value for android 10.

Following limitation, I found on [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data).

> **Limited access to clipboard data.**
>
> Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app
>   that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on
>   Android 10 or higher.

Is there any way I can enable focus when button on the widget is pressed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your window should be focused when accessing Clipboard:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if(hasFocus){
        val clipboard =
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val item: ClipData.Item = clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0)
        val serial: String = item.text.toString()
    }
}
```

This should work inside your activity.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I want to perform paste operation in my widget which is located on the device's home screen,